# jQuery UI Dialog failing in Google Sites

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, sites

I am trying to use Google Sites to create a simple jQuery UI dialog with the HTML Box widget.  I am using the following code, which works fine in a normal web page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true }); /*, {modal : true} */

   $('.clickable').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog( "open" );
   });
});  
</script>

<div class="clickable">Show log</div>

<div id="dialog" title="event log">
  This is a test dialog
</div>
```

Two issues:

1. Google sites tells me that the jquery UI CSS is not loadable (even though its hosted through ajax.googleapis
2. The dialog doesn't show up when I click the ".clickable" div.

Any guidance?  I know the obvious solution is to not use Google Sites, but its required for my workplace.

Extra info:

1. I am only using an old version of jquery-ui because its the only link that would load through the Google Sites HTML Box widget
2. Google Sites says that HTML boxes are prohibited from interacting with any external sites except for the ajax.googleapis links that are provided.  Does anyone know if this could be causing the dialog to fail?  Other UI features seem to work (tested "blind" effect successfully).

Comment: What's the exact error in console? I'd suggest using protocol agnostic links for libs, google usually likes to serve https I believe. `//ajax.google.etcetc`. Also, not sure if relevant since no href attr, But may want to preventDefault on the anchor click event.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "error in console"?  I'm just trying to produce an effect on click.  I did make the links protocol agnostic and it didn't help the css link, but thank you for the suggestion.  I updated my code to use a div for the ".clickable" class because it was breaking it to set href="javascript:;" or href="#"

Comment: If you're in chrome, right click anywhere on the web page and select "Inspect element". Then go to the console tab and see if any red errors are displayed. It usually is a good indication of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ChristopherMarshall.  I wasn't able to solve my problem, but in the process of trouble-shooting realized that this was only the tip of the iceberg and that I need to investigate other options to execute my end goal.  Thanks again, I'm going to consider this closed.